# how to get rid of these modelling artifacts?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, artifacts, subsurface-scattering

i just ran into a problem.
how to do i get rid of these artifacts
i am not that much Pro as I have just started modelling
I really would like to have a car model of my own but I am unable to find the problem in the image

is this because of vertices? kindly help

[image]

Comment: I think it will be necessary to see your .blend file, you can uploat it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  One thing I can notice is that you use subdivision modifier before mirror modifier, usually you want to first merge two sides with mirror before applying subdivision. Though your particular errors are probably caused by incorrect topology, e.g. some vertices are not merged while they should be, or there's not enough geometry (no holding edges).